# How to design a data structure to store unlimited data you can say infinite data that are always in increasing order

Tags: data-structures

I have to design a data structure that supports billions of data insertion that are always in increasing order, make sure insertion, deletion and search operations complexity is minimum.

suppose data is defined as

```
typedef struct data
     {
      int a; 
      int b;
}data;
```

where b is always increasing.

I have implemented DS as a dynamic list of 1000 data in a single block with a next block pointer. e.g

```
typedef struct block
{
   int size; // curr element count.
   int capacity; //1000 elements.
   data* pArr;   // malloc 1000 data elements.
   struct block* pNext;
}block;
```

My data structure is good in searching and insertion but after deletion of data it is not reusable, rebuilding is costly.

I am looking for a better DS implementation.

Comment: This is an extremely vague question, and your title is confusing. You should try to boil down your question to something simple which is the core of your problem, and if possible explain what you have researched and tried in order to solve it yourself.

Comment: How often are items deleted? If not often, you could just use an array of arrays, and mark items as deleted. Insertion is O(1) (just append to the list). Search is a matter of binary searching to determine which block the item is in, and then searching that block for the item. Deletion is a search followed by marking the item as deleted. If you end up with a lot of empty spots, then you'll have to rebuild the structure from time to time, to remove the dead space.

Comment: @JimMischel  thanks, you got my question perfectly. I have edited question for more clarity but rebuilding is costly when data size become huge. looking for more efficient method.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a linked list of blocks. With a billion items, you'd end up with a million blocks of 1,000 items. I would instead recommend an array of your `block` structures, and add a `min` and `max` value to each block. That way you can binary search the blocks to determine which one contains the item, and then binary search the individual array. I also would recommend that you make your blocks larger. You're probably better off having 1,000 blocks of a million items each rather than a million blocks of a thousand items each.

Comment: Of course, you'll have to re-allocate your blocks array from time to time, when the count exceeds the capacity, but the blocks array should be relatively small. Rebuilding doesn't have to involve totally rewriting the structure. You should be able to come up with a way to combine adjacent blocks when one's fill ratio falls below some threshold, and remove blocks that become empty.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel  thanks for explanation, I got some idea of merging two blocks and  deleting a complete block if two adjacent blocks size == capacity. This way space is optimized, now it is improved from previous implementation.